# How to Create VPN Profile and Connect to it in android Programmatically?

Tags: android, vpn

We are developing an Android app that needs to connect to a VPN. The problem that we have is that the users that are going to use this app, do not have any knowledge about Creating VPN profiles, to connect then to it, and then to connect to the app etc.

So, we are obligated to find a way when our Application starts, to connect to the VPN (we will hard code all the requirements needed). But the problem is that we searched on the internet and we couldn't find anything :(.

I wanted to ask you, is there anyway to Create a VPN Profile programmatically, and then Connect to it after the creation?

The VPN Profile that we need (VPN profile data that wee need to fill):

**Name**: ________

**Type**: **IPSec Xauth PSK**

**Servber address**: __________

**IPSec identifier**: __________

**IPSec pre-shared key**: ___________

**Username**: ______________

**Password**: ______________

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: Did you find solution for your problem? :) Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution?Thanks

Comment: anyone have a solution on this, please?

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically add VPN profiles, there doesn't seem to be any Android API to do this. There is a VPNService and VPNService.Builder classes that will allow you to create and connect a VPN within your application.

I believe what you're looking to do though is add a new entry in the Android settings VPN list. This can be done via Samsung KNOX for devices that support KNOX via this KNOX API: https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-premium/reference/com/sec/enterprise/knox/GenericVpnPolicy.html

Comment: Tnks Wesley, do u have an example about VPNService.Builder?.Tnks a lot.

Comment: Here's the Google documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn

And here's the sample app mentioned above.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn